# Why does TokenOrigin always return the same value?

Tags: windows

I'm trying to determine the logon session ID for a particular user process.  To do this, I've retrieved the process token and then called [GetTokenInformation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa446671(v=vs.85).aspx) with the TokenOrigin option.

However, the answer always seems to be 0x3E7, even if I have two different users logged in simultaneously.  Obviously that can't be right.

What is TokenOrigin actually looking up, and what is the significance of 0x3E7 in particular?  How do I get the real logon session ID for a token?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [documentation for TOKEN_INFORMATION_CLASS,](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379626(v=vs.85).aspx) under TokenOrigin, says:

> If the token resulted from a logon that used explicit credentials, such as passing a name, domain, and password to the LogonUser function, then the TOKEN_ORIGIN structure will contain the ID of the logon session that created it.

That kind of *sounds* as if it means the logon session that the token belongs to, but if you read it carefully it *could* equally well mean the logon session associated with the process that performed the authentication operation, and it turns out that is indeed what is returned.  In Windows 7, 0x3E7 is usually the logon session of `winlogon.exe` which is responsible for authenticating interactive logons.

If we [look under logon identifier in the glossary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms721592(v=vs.85).aspx#_security_logon_identifier_gly) it says:

> To retrieve the logon ID from an access token, call the GetTokenInformation function for TokenStatistics; the logon ID is in the AuthenticationId member.

I have confirmed that this works as expected.